# Why does this regex return None

Tags: python, regex, string, match

I cannot figure out why this is not matching. I would really appreciate if somebody can help me here.

```
print(re.match(r"Newton", "Isaac Newton , physicist"))
```

Comment: `re.match` only matches the *start* of the string.

Comment: Because your string doesn't start with `Newton`. Perhaps you wanted `re.search`

Comment: Documentation for the re module for python 2.7 is here https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html - scroll down to find `match`

Answer (score 0):

`re.match` matches at the beginning of the string only, use `re.search` to find the first match anywhere in the string (see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)).

Comment: At least link to the Python documentation...?

Comment: Fair enough added it